# Send and retrieve data from android app to vb.net web server using web service

Tags: android, vb.net, web-services

I'm a newbie in android and .NET.
In my final year project I'm developing an android app for storing pictures in cloud. I have a similar type of website created in vb.net.
I have to use the .NET server for storing images. I also have to use the same database as of my website. After a little bit of research I find that a web service is required for this purpose, but I do not know anything about web service.
I have found that volly can be used for sending JSON data to web service. But do not know how to implement this.
If any one can tell me how to create a web service in vb.net to receive JSON formatted POST data and send back a response to the android app.

Sorry for my terrific English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for ASP.Net Core with MVC or Web API.

Comment: as a newbie I don't know about MVC. So web api would do the job for me I think.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Comment: @iRJ you should do your own research before asking questions here and need to show some examples what you've tried so far. If you only ask solution how to do something, you may get negative votes from some users.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman thanks for the link. It really helped me to understand volly.

Comment: @Mahib thanks for your suggestion. I will add my android code soon. But I want to know the Web service code.

Comment: @Mahib Sometimes folks do not the right search terms. I've had this problem and I imagine it's 10x worse for a non-native english speaker.